# Outlook "failed to extract credentials" message

Tags: windows, outlook, credentials

We have some problems with Outlook and Exchange.
We have a user, lets say it's user 'Trainee1'. It's linked to the mailbox 'Trainee@company.nl', and when initializing outlook, we fill in the credentials of this mailbox as user: domain\trainee, with the password of this account.

Instantly we get a red message, below the credentials box, "Failed to extract credentials".

Any clue what this can be?

I'm not sure if it's something in Outlook, Windows or Exchange.
The message is shown in the 'standard' windows credentials popup.

[edit]
Screenshot of the error

[image: Screenshot of the error]

Comment: Did someone translate that message to English? It sounds rather strange. What was it in the original language?

Comment: @MichaelHampton This is the original error message...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just got a call from ESET, the problem seems to be ESET Secure Authentication version 2.8.22

Answer (score 0):

Clear the relevant Outlook credentials in the Credential Manager: open control penal>user accounts>Credential Manager>Windows Credentials, then restart Outlook and re-enter the correct credentials.
If it doesn’t work, close Outlook and recreate a profile: open control panel>user accounts >Mail>show profiles>Add> follow the wizard to reconfigure the mailbox, and then select the newly created configuration in the always use the profile. Restart Outlook and see if it has any effect.
By the way, would you please post a screenshot of the error message you got here?

Comment: No credentials stored overthere. Already tried to create a new profile. Will add image in original post

Comment: Have you tried adding the account in control panel? Can this account be added properly?  Then hold ctrl key on and click the icon of Outlook on task bar. Click Connection status to check if the connection is established.

Comment: @BeverlyGoa Yes I did. I could add the account without any problems overthere. Once I opened outlook, same problem again.

Comment: Can you log in through OWA? If not, how about changing the location of the mailbox to another database using Set-mailbox -Identity user@domain.com -Database <database name>

Comment: Yes, OWA is no problem

Comment: Since OWA is no problem, the issue must be related to your Outlook client or windows systems. Have you recently done an upgrade of them? Can you log in to other users through this Outlook client? How about reinstall the client?

Comment: Looks like a windows problem, accessing a share on another computer, with other credentials than my current logged in user, gives the same problem

Comment: How's going on now? Has the issue been resolved?

Comment: No.. Still having the issues